# Search Feature using .Contains with terms within a one field

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, search

I have built a search feature for a product site. The search works fine. Recently, we have added a SearchTerm field in the database. 
SearchTerm Data example: "work shoes blue black gear"
Current code is

```
    pM = (from p in ctx.Products
                      where
                            p.productSearchField.Contains(term) ||
                            p.productName.Contains(term)
                      select p).ToList()
```

If the term = "shoes" <-- works

If the term = "work shoes" <-- works

If the term = "black shoes" <-- does NOT work.

I also tried to separate the SearchTerm Data by commas, but that did not work.
Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the term into single terms. See if any match:

```
term.Split(' ').Any(i => p.productSearchField.Contains(i))
```

Or if every word has to match:

```
term.Split(' ').All(i => p.productSearchField.Contains(i))
```

---

EDIT

```
             var terms = term.Split(' ');
             pM = (from p in ctx.Products
                  where
                        terms.All(i => p.productSearchField.Contains(i)) ||
                        p.productName.Contains(term)
                  select p).ToList()
```

Comment: I am getting an error running eitherone: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I was worried about that. The documentation is weird concerning it, but my edit should fix that.