# Search with multiple terms using contains

Tags: c#, linq, search, contains

I have tried to modify the solution [Search Feature using .Contains with terms within a one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450887/search-feature-using-contains-with-terms-within-a-one-field) but need some help.

I have an object structure of:

```
public class product
     {
        public string productID {get;set;}
        public List<searchTerms> searchTerms {get; set;}
     }

    public class searchTerms 
    {
        public string searchTerm {get; set;}
    }
```

I want to return a new List where the searchTerm is matched. I've tried:

```
matchedProds = (
            from p in prods
            where p.searchTerms.Contains(term)
            select p
            ).ToList();
```

But cannot make it work with either term as a literal string or as a searchTerm.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var matchedProds = (
        from p in prods
        where p.searchTerms.Any(st => st.searchTerm == term)
        select p
        ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var products = allProducts.Where(m => m.searchTerms.Any(n => n.searchTerm == input)).ToList()
```